# PHP - Cut last N chars in string faster than substr($s, 0, -$N)

Tags: php, string, trim, substr

I have a script trimming strings this way billions of times.

```
$s = substr($s, 0, -$n);
```

Is there a way to do it faster an without reassigning the string?

Comment: Any examples of input and output?

Comment: Well, to really just cut from string, there isn't a faster way, since substr is an internal method.

Comment: You can do it with `$string = sprinft("%s.$len-N", $string)`... but, you are reassigning, and.. i think is more slow.. try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition strings are not mutable in PHP. To "cut" a string, you'll have to create a new string based on the original string, making it necessary to reassign it. The code you have is probably already the most minimalist way to do it.